# curl and wget not working with https sites after upgrade to ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, wget, openssl, curl, https

Seems to be a openssl related issue. Anyone have any ideas as to what this is?

Note that the url works in a browser.

With wget:

```
# wget -d https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x

DEBUG output created by Wget 1.19.4 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/user/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'setup_8.x' (UTF-8) -> 'setup_8.x' (UTF-8)
--2018-09-02 19:54:06--  https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x
Could not seed PRNG; consider using --random-file.
OpenSSL: error:2406F07A:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Not a regular file
Disabling SSL due to encountered errors.
```

With curl:

```
# curl -v -L https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x

*   Trying 205.251.207.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to deb.nodesource.com (205.251.207.2) port 443 (#0)

<hangs>
```